# SQL Server Setup Failure on installing SSMS

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, windows-xp-sp2

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 & SQL Server Management Studio on a virtualized Windows XP SP2 (using VmWare).

I already installed SQL Server successfully, but I can't install Management Studio because of this error:

[image]

could you help, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you close install center during the setup? If so, it has to stay open during the install process, https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/388671/installation-center-must-stay-open-throughout-setup.

The Connect article is for an older version but I'm guessing it still applies to R2.